# not able to view images and video both in gallery

Tags: android, cordova

i am trying to fetch the gallery for photos and videos stored in my android phone using PhoneGap ,

here is my code , but the issue is i can see only images but no videos.

what i want is when i open a gallery i want to show image and videos both as of now i can only see the Images. i have specified the `mediaType` to `ALLMEDIA` but no effect.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(
                uploadPhoto,
                function(message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
                {
                    quality         : 50,
                    destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                    sourceType      :  navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                    mediaType       : navigator.camera.ALLMEDIA
                }
            );


   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution , there was a mistake in my code i have written `navigator.camera.ALLMEDIA` instead of `navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA`